# Excel, automatic change text to date by replace

Tags: excel

I have some problem with Excel. I have data like

```
10,1
11,1
... etc.
```

I need to change it to

```
10.1
11.1
... etc.
```

Everything is in the text format. When I d it manually, that's OK, but if i press Ctrl+H replace , to . it automatically converts to date. I have tried to change formats, bu that doesn't work.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: I solved it by 
=IF(IFERROR(FIND(",";G2);0)=0;G2;REPLACE(G2;FIND(",";G2);1;"."))
but i believe there is another way

Comment: Do you **want** the result to become a true number with a decimal portion or is this some sort of text-based organizational system? e.g. 1.09, 1.10, 1.11, etc.

Comment: It is text-based, account number.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to use Ctrl+H for this task - it always tries to be smart and therefore converts the result to a date.

If you want to use a formula, try

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(G2,",",".",1),G2)
```